# vue js dynamic class add

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want to add a dynamic class in bootstrap dropdown button . when I open dropdown and select a menu item its add a dynamic class and not auto close menu items .

when add a dyanmic class in button its remove bootstrap show class.

```
<button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light dropdown-toggle" 
         :class="{'btn-primary': !allType}" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
 Type <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-right"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap and other libraries like jQuery aren't completely compatible with Vue because they have different architectures.

Bootstrap manipulates DOM directly, while Vue renders DOM based on virtual DOM changes thus overwriting any Bootstrap's DOM changes.

**Unfortunately Vue doesn't care about safe handling of existing DOM, it just overwrites it.**

So you should toggle your class also with pure DOM directly (not with `:class` which overwrites any direct DOM changes).

So in short you shouldn't mix DOM manipulations with Vue dynamic features.

You could use `watchEffect`:

```
onMounted(() => {
  watchEffect(() => button.value.classList.toggle('btn-primary', !allType.value));
});

...
<button ref="button" ...
```